# How can I highlight many code blocks [code][/code] with PHP?

Tags: php, syntax-highlighting, codeblocks

Hello I have a dynamic text and I want to add code like all the forums like this: 
[code]My code here...[/code]

Is there an easy way to have a function in PHP to do this stuff?? For example if I write on my text:

Hello world example with PHP [code]echo "hello "world";[/code] and an addition example with PHP [code] echo 5+5; //The result will be 10[/code] etc...

Will apear:

Hello world example  with PHP

```
<?php echo "hello "world"; ?>
```

and an addition example  with PHP

```
<?php echo 5+5; //The result will be 10 ?>
```

etc....

Comment: I actually use Geshi syntax-highlighting and I just want to take back the block values to use preg_replace is there any way?

Comment: Click the `edit` link below your question if you wish to add more info. If your comment is in response to `Mob`'s answer then add the comment directly below his answer.

Answer (score 2):

In addition, you can use this PHP syntax-highlighting library. [Geshi](http://qbnz.com/highlighter/)

Answer (score 0):

Simple case scenario (no nesting, other weird formatting):

```
$text = preg_replace('#\[code\](.*?)\[\/code\]#s', '<div class="whatever">$1</div>', $text);
```

Comment: I actually use Geshi syntax-highlighting and I just want to take back the block values to use preg_replace is there any way?